# How to intergrate paypal in Indian website to recieve payment in INR?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

- we are trishlaemart we use magento 1.9. for our website.
- we are looking our international customers to make payment in `INR`.
- We tried many ways but not working, we are using `EBS` payment gateway for support.
- which helps to get payment in paypal but the currency is not getting converted into `INR`

**Example**: 100 INR is there as product means its taking as 100 `USD`.

Anyone help us to solve this issue